# RTK Query - eslint gives errors @typescript-eslint/no-invalid-void-type if query's parameter is void

Tags: reactjs, eslint, rtk-query, typescript-eslint

I have a query function without parameter.

```
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    fetchEvents: build.query<Test[], void>({
      query: () => '/test'
    }),
  })
```

ES-Lint errors:

> void is only valid as a return type or generic type argument
> @typescript-eslint/no-invalid-void-type

What should be used instead of `void`?

#### Update

This is my `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "standard-with-typescript",
        'eslint:recommended',
        "prettier"
    ],
    "overrides": [

    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module",
        "project": "./tsconfig.json",
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint",
        "prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions": ["error", "type"],
        
    },
    settings: {
        "react": {
            "version": "detect",
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried with `undefined`?

Comment: `void` is what is used in the RTK query doc in this example https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript#typing-providestagsinvalidatestags

Is es-lint erroring or it's just a warning?

Comment: @leo updated my question. It errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a warning (or error) because someone in your project decided it should be an error - it has no technical reason and can be changed in your eslint configuration at any time.

Redux Toolkit uses the `void` type here - it is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: By default it warns.

Comment: This is not even part of the "default settings", it's only part of the "strict" recommendations which are very opinionated and will warn you about a lot of things that might make sense or not depending on your application. And if you use RTK, it does not make sense - since that relies on `void` in some cases.

Comment: I just updated my question. Do you know where it comes from?

Comment: No, but you can just disable it by adding this to "rules":  `"@typescript-eslint/no-invalid-void-type": 0`

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to `warn` by using `"@typescript-eslint/no-invalid-void-type": ["warn"]`

Comment: If you want warnings about code that is meant to be written like that - I'd reconsider. It could confuse the next person on your project.